# Made a new rig for a model, but some materials do not move along with the mesh when I try to pose

Tags: rigging, objects

I'm still pretty green to this, but progress is being made. Anyway, here's the issue.

Had a pre-existing model, but dis-liked the rig so I thought I'd make a new one. Everything turned out fine (after many attempts), but when I go into pose mode, parts of the hair don't move along with the rest of the mesh.

[image: Hair Loss]

The old rig did have bones for part of the hair, but before making the new rig I joined all the parts of the mesh together. Never used it anyway.(The hair bones).

I figure I could either make armature for the hair and parent it to the new rig.Or maybe I thought I could just do a weight transfer, but since it's all joined together now into the one mesh I can't really do that... as far as I know.

Saw another solution about assigning the active materials, but that just made his entire body hair. Like Cousin It! I started poking around at things like geometry nodes, but a lot of that is beyond me at this point. As I said, noob.

Thought I'd just ask instead of wasting more time and limited brain cells trying to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to go into edit mode, select all the hair that's not moving, and assign it to the head bone with 1.0 Weight.

When you joined the hair mesh with the other mesh, if there were hair vertex groups they would persist on the combined mesh even when the bones were removed.

I put together a small demonstration to show what I  mean, with a cube and its very sparse remaining hair.

1. First I show that the hair isn't tied to any bone by going into pose mode, moving the Head bone, and showing the head moves but the hair are stationary.
2. Then I select my mesh, go into edit mode, and with the Hair vertex group selected, press the Select button to select the vertices in that group. If you don't have a Hair vertex group, simply select the vertices on your mesh that you want to follow the head.
3. Next I select the Head vertex group, and with the hair vertices selected I press Assign to give them a weight of 1.0 so they follow the Head bone.
4. Lastly I go into pose mode and demonstrate the hair now follows the Head bone.

[image]

One last thing, I don't see how "assigning the active materials" relates to this problem, that's only for giving faces different materials so they have a different appearance or colour and it has nothing to do with rigging to my knowledge.

Comment: It appears to have worked. Appreciate it.

Took a moment because all the vertex groups from the old armature were still listed until I realized I should probably assign it with the NEW ones, huh?

As I said, I'm a noob. I'm slowly but surely figuring this stuff out. Thanks again!